# Programmatically setting properties when using @KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm using the `@KafkaListener` annotation in my spring boot app without creating a custom `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean.  I'm currently setting the `spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer` property in my application.yml file to assign my deserializer and prefer to do this programmatically to have compile time checks.  I realize creating my own `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` allows me to set this property on the factory, but I'd like to avoid the boiler plate and some extra complications around getting the SSL setup.

Is there a simple way to set my value deserializer programmatically without creating my own `KafkaListenerContainerFactory`?

Comment: `Is there a simple way to set my value deserializer programmatically without creating my own KafkaListenerContainerFactory` yes you can do this, but i really don't understand your requirement, can you please explain a bit more, or upload the code you have and show something what changes you need

Comment: What do you mean by "set the value programmatically" -- like, do you want to create a deserializer bean? Like Deadpool said above, it's not quite clear what your use case is.

Comment: I believe he wants type safety on the deserializer (rather than expressing the class name as a String). See my answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell, yes I was looking for type safety, and that's a reasonable solution.  I knew the properties were only on the ConsumerFactory, but didn't know I could get away with only creating that bean.  Makes sense. I like the simplicity of using the `@KafkaListener` annotation and was trying to avoid the rest of the boiler plate just to set one property.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deserializer goes on properties used to create the consumer factory, not the container factory, you can override boot's consumer factory as follows:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumerFactory(KafkaProperties properties) {
    Map<String, Object> props = properties.buildConsumerProperties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#properties--)

You can set additional properties like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test-transactional",
               properties={"foo:bar","isolation.level:read_committed"})
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr) throws Exception {
    logger.info("got consumer record" + cr.toString());
}


@KafkaListener(topics = "test-transactional",        
                         properties={"isolation.level:read_uncommitted"})
public void listenDifferent(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr) throws Exception {
    logger.info("uncomitted: got consumer record" + cr.toString());
}
```